# Multiple quaternion multiplication

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

```
//q1、q2 and q3 can be any quaternions only if q1 != q2 != q3
Quaternion q1 = Quaternion.Euler(10, 10, 10);
Quaternion q2 = Quaternion.Euler(20, 20, 20);
Quaternion q3 = Quaternion.Euler(20, 30, 30);

Vector3 v = Vector3.one;
Vector3 v1 = (q1 * q2 * q3) * v;
Vector3 v2 = q3 * (q2 * (q1 * v));

Debug.LogFormat("{0} {1}", v1.ToString("F3"), v2.ToString("F3"));
```

The result of output indicates that v1 != v2,which means the two-way rotation operation are different.Why?

Comment: Vector3 v1 = (q1 * q2 * q3) * v;
Vector3 v2 = q3 * (q2 * (q1 * v));

Indentical will be

Vector3 v1 = (q1 * q2 * q3) * v;
Vector3 v2 = q1 * (q2 * (q3 * v));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quaternions are not commutative. So as soon as you change the order in which you multiply them the value you get will be different too.

From the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html)

> Rotating by the product lhs * rhs is the same as applying the two
>   rotations in sequence: lhs first and then rhs, relative to the
>   reference frame resulting from lhs rotation. Note that this means
>   rotations are not commutative, so lhs * rhs does not give the same
>   rotation as rhs * lhs.

The order in both multiplication is not the same. Yes you are starting with `q1` and finishing with `q3` but the order left to right isn't the same.

```
Vector3 v1 = (q1 * q2 * q3) * v;
```

In the first you'll have your results of `q1 * q2` and then multiply it by `q3`

```
Vector3 v2 = q3 * (q2 * (q1 * v));
```

while in the second one you'll have `q3` and then multiply it by the result of `q2 * (q1 * v)`

So as you can see you're not conserving the original order in the second equation and because they're not commutative your results will be different.

Comment: Thanks first.Well,I know quaternions are not commutative.I mean,the orders of the three quaternions multiplication are the same:q1 first,then q2 and q3 at last.The difference between them is that,it computes combining rotation first and then applys to the vector 'v' in way-one,but applys to 'v' each time in same sequence in way-two.Isn't it?

Comment: @ZhangMing The order in both multiplication is not the same. Yes you are starting with q1 and finishing with q3 but the order left to right isn't the same. In the first you'll have your results of q1 * q2 and then multiply it by q3 while in the second one you'll have q3 and then multiply it by q2 * (q1 * v) and because they are not commutative this will result in different values.

Comment: @ZhangMing Could you add the results of `v1` and `v2`?

Comment: v1:(1.122, 0.775, 1.068)  v2:(1.161, 0.791, 1.013)

Comment: I think I've got it.Change the second one to:Vector3 v2 = q1 * (q2 * (q3 * v)).This will be the same order as the first one.And the computered result also shows v1==v2.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ZhangMing Yes that's a lot better because you're keeping the same order left to right and you're welcome.